# Complex numbers finding real values of x and y

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Im having trouble where to go next?

Solving the real values of x and y

$2+x+jy=(x-jy)(5+j6)$

Here's my working

$2+x+jy=(x-jy)(5+j6)$

$2+x+jy= 5x+6y+j6x-j5y$

Real numbers
$2+x=5x+6y$

Imaginary numbers
$j6x-j5y=jy$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now have a set of equations, two equations for two variables. Have you tried to solve the system?

$$2+x=5x + 6y\\
6x - 5y = y$$

It isn't all that hard to solve...

Comment: i dont know if i'm applying the correct method. I've got y=3/7?

Comment: @user159676 It's a system with two equations and two variables. What did you do to try to solve it?

Comment: what i did was multiple by 6 on the first equation from there 12-5y=30+37y then -5y-37y=30-12 finally i've got 42y=18, y=-3/7

Comment: How did you get $12-5y = 30 + 37y$?

Comment: @user159676 Just in case you are still wondering, the solutions are $x=y=\frac15$.